# First name is not displaying in android using arraylist

Tags: android

Hi in the below first name is not passing correctly to another activity.Can any one help me.

I am comparing my username with user_name if both are equal then I am sending my first name to another activity.

Support my username is admin and user_name is admin then I am able to pass the first name from the api. If it is second list item it is not working.

```
 private void fetchUserJSON(final String sessionId, final String username){

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Write code for your refresh logic
//                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
//                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
//                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
//                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
//                progressDialog.show();
               // sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionId");
                //username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
                String operation = "query";
                String query = "select  *  from Users";
                final GetNoticeDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetNoticeDataService.class);
                /** Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the notice data*/
                Call<UserModule> call = service.UserRecordDetails(operation, sessionId, query);
                /**Log the URL called*/
                Log.i("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");
                call.enqueue(new Callback<UserModule>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UserModule> call, Response<UserModule> response) {
                        Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                            UserModule userModule = response.body();
                            String success = userModule.getSuccess();
                            if (success.equals("true")) {
                                Results_Users results = userModule.getResult();
                                records = results.getRecords();
                                for (Records records1 : records) {
                                    String user_name = records1.getUser_name();

                                        String id = records1.getId();
                                        Log.d("id",id);
                                        String first_name = records1.getFirst_name();
                                        String last_name = records1.getLast_name();
                                        String email1=records1.getEmail1();
                                        String title=records1.getTitle();
                                        Records records=new Records(user_name,title,first_name,last_name,email1,id);
                                        recordsList.add(records);

                                }
                                if(username.equals(recordsList.get(0).getUser_name()))
                                    i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("first_name", recordsList.get(2).getFirst_name());
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UserModule> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                    //     progressDialog.dismiss();
                });
            }
        }, 0);
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: `Records records2=recordsList.get(user_name.indexOf(user_name));` what is your purpose on there? Because `user_name.indexOf(user_name)` is always `0`

Comment: if the username are matches then want to send firstname from the arraylist

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz how to get the position

Comment: You can just pass this: `final String first_name = records1.getFirst_name();`. You already set it above for each iteration. So it keeps your current `records1`'s `first_name`. But also I should mention that your code needs a lot of refactoring.

Comment: final String first_name = records1.getFirst_name(); everytime it is checking only first item from the arraylist

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz list of objects

Comment: Because you define it as final. I think you don't need it.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz i have edited my code .Now it is giving my last list first name

Answer (score 0):

Remove final from for loop

```
for (Records records1 : records) {
```

Comment: what is return type of results.getRecords() ? It must be an array of Records.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the logic of your whole code. But you can edit your loop like this:

```
String first_name = null;

for (Records records1 : records) {
    if (username.equals(records1.getUser_name())) {
        first_name = records1.getFirst_name();
        break;
    }
}

i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("first_name", first_name);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: For arraylist contains a list of string.All the strings I am adding to arraylist

Comment: can we move to chat discussion

Comment: You add your logic to where you want. And yes I can help trough chat.

Comment: first list conatins a username admin and first name is Admin.Second list contains username is abc and first name abcdef.If I am login with abc as a username that time first name is giving empty

Comment: I am not able to moving to chat discussion

Comment: I am not able to sending messages

Comment: Because you need 20 reputation for it. Edit code above and add what you want inside the loop.

Comment: What are `0` and `2` in get methods?

Comment: I am not able finding the postion for constructor

Comment: where can i find your mail id

Comment: 0 is username and 2 is first name

Comment: You add multiple Records object to recordList. So recordList.get(0) is first object (an instance of Records class) and recordList.get(2) is third object (an instance of Records class). So it's wrong.